# Creating Search Index from Multiple indexes within same search service

Tags: autosuggest, azure-qna-maker

I have to create a Auto Suggestions for a chatbot with suggestions coming from QnA Maker KB. There are 5 different knowledge base and a respective index created for the same in Azure Search service. I am able to query and get suggestions from each index or a testkb index. But is there a feature available which can search through all the indexes within the same search service and return me the appropriate result.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to generate the suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we do not have any feature that allows you to search through all the indexes within the same search service. However, you can try out a few options:

- You can use [Dispatch](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch) as a **routing service**, to distribute requests to different KBs in the backend, without the need to implement a custom routing solution.
- Or you could use a higher level QnA Maker to ask a question with multiple follow-up questions and have the user select one of the follow-up question options and then send that selected option to the bot to route manually to the correct KB.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, can you please accept the answer so that it helps others as well? Thanks