# How/why/when is a resource's testkb index is created?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search, azure-ai

image of azure cognitive search where there are two indexes for few project MARKED IN RED and no extra index for other project

[image]

some recources have testkb index auto created and some don't.
Why there is no testkb index for all the resources in a search service?
Is there a way to avoid testkb index created for all the resources in a search service?
What is the reason for the testkb index created automatically?

Gone through the microsoft doc on indexes, where I couldn't find solution for my questions.

Comment: it would be great if you provide more details like what you tried and where you are getting blockers . As you said some resources have testkb please provide those  detals.

Comment: @vijaya I have attached the image above

Answer (score 0):

> For this some recources have testkb index auto created and some don't...

Yes, as you said sometimes it's auto created. For testing purpose i created 3 cognitive search services as shown in below images.

- As there is no particular document about testkb so tried from my end by taking different pricing tiers and different loaction to check is they causing testkb auto creation.
- Here i am taking Basic and central us as you can see there is no testkb.
  [image]
- Then in standard with different loaction created another cognitive search but still there is no testkb auto created.
  [image]
- Finally created other cognitive as Basic tier and here testkb is auto created when i created some other indexes which contains stoarge.
  [image]
  From all these one thing is clear it's not depending pricing tier and loaction.
- As the search results do not clearly address why certain resources in a search service have a testkb index automatically built while others do not, or how to stop the testkb index from being created for all resources in a search service. AFAIK The testkb index, however, seems to be unique to particular platforms or services, like Azure Search.

> For this Is there a way to avoid testkb index created for all the resources in
> a search service?

- AFAIK there is a no such direct way to avoid this but if you don't want you can delete that. Indexes are typically used to accelerate and optimise data retrieval processes on a database or search service. Depending on the service or platform being utilised, the precise reasons why the testkb index is automatically built may vary.

**Note**: Below are the only documents available regarding testkb.

- But after deleting we can restore that created testkb as per this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/troubleshooting#manage-service).
- Refer these MS [document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/azure-resources) and [document2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/limits#knowledge-bases) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61499435/creating-search-index-from-multiple-indexes-within-same-search-service) questions  which have some inforamtion about testkb it may helps.